# Lazy Load YouTube on Resize

Tags: javascript, performance, youtube, embed, lazy-loading

I have 2 different YouTube videos for 2 specific screen widths.

I'd like to load each video dynamically, exclusively when a visitor hits that screen size, as opposed to loading them when the document is loaded.

```
<div id="size1000">
  <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tR-5AZF9zPI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="size500">
  <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tR-K69A1lL1PHQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

css

```
#size1000, #size500{
   display:none;
}
@media(width:1000px){
    #size1000{
      display:block;
    }
}
@media(width:500px){
    #size500{
      display:block;
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how is this done?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the HTML in question and then somebody could help by just filling in the blanks rather than having to create the entire scenario to illustrate how the solution would be implemented.

Comment: I agree, yet it will help you get your question answered by reducing the amount of work a potential helpful person would have to expend to come up with a solution.  Also, in general, questions with code are more likely to get looked at closely.

Answer (score 1):

Since I misunderstood what you were asking for, here's a simple example that uses Javascript to detect the client width and display the proper YouTube tag, if any, based on the screen size.

[Here's another Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/e9fRrM?p=preview). You will need to stop and re-run it after each change in the frame width, unlike the with media query example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    if (document.body.clientWidth >= 1000) {
      document.write('<iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tR-5AZF9zPI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    } else if (document.body.clientWidth >= 500) {
      document.write('<iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tR-K69A1lL1PHQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This doesn't handle the display size changing dynamically, such as with an orientation change.  You'd have to hook onto the event to do that.  But it shows you the basics.

**Update:** Here's the basic form for acting on a screen resize event. There should be plenty of questions here dealing with that.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

I hope this is what you mean.  If not, I give up. ;)

Comment: Hey that's not bad. Do you know if the condition makes the request to youtube when the document is loaded or when the screen size is hit ?

Comment: @propster When the document is loaded.  Like I mentioned, it's not dynamic.  It makes the decision based on the page dimensions at load time. I added a small snipet showing how you get the size change event.

Comment: I see, so I still gotta chisel my question. Thanks for helping me do that :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Only display the first if the screen is from 500 to 999px in width, the other only when 1000px or greater?

```
#size1000, #size500{
   display:none;
}
@media(min-width:500px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    #size500{
      display:block;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1000px){
    #size1000{
      display:block;
    }
}
```

Note that this is loading both, but only displaying only the one (or none for small screens).  If the videos are auto-play, that might be an issue.

Here's a working [Plunk demo of it](http://plnkr.co/edit/fNhtbR?p=preview).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I want no video to load until a visitor hits that screen size. This has nothing to do with CSS

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot tho.

Comment: It doesn't show anything at all if the width is less than 500.  Try adjusting the window in the plunk to less than 500 and you will see no video at all.  That's why the min-width: 500px is there, so that you need to be at least that size to see size500.

Comment: You do not understand. It is not about seeing the video. It is about the browser loading the video in the background. This is a question to optimize performance.

Comment: You are right, I did not understand.  You should improve your question to make it obvious what, exactly, you are looking for.  Instead you would need to use Javascript to detect the screen size and render appropriately.  You aren't looking for media queries at all, so you should probably remove that from your question as it's misleading.